# Timer scope issue with #selector

Tags: swift, timer, scope

I'm stuck with getting this into the right scope. I'm sure its something super simple but I'm banging my head against a wall with it. any answers i'm finding are in earlier version of swift so im struggling to understand how to solve this

My current issue is trying to get the timer initialised correctly and counting. the "selector" is causing the most issues. the rest i'm sure ill be able to figure out afterwards

code is as follows.

```
    @IBOutlet weak var shortTimerLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var longTimerLabel: UILabel!

var seconds = 60 //This variable will hold a starting value of seconds. It could be any amount above 0.
var timer = Timer()
var isTimerRunning = false //This will be used to make sure only one timer is created at a time.

@IBAction func longpressed(_ gestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
  shortTimerLabel.text = "longPressed"

}
@IBAction func tappedShortTimer(_ gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
  shortTimerLabel.text = "ShortPressed"
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    func runTimer() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self,   selector: #selector(updateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
    func updateTimer() {
        seconds += 1     //This will decrement(count down)the seconds.
        shortTimerLabel.text = "\(seconds)" //This will update the label.
    }
}
```

im trying to create a stopwatch which can be controlled using gestures. short pressed on label for stop/start and long press to reset time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `updateTimer()` method, the first line should read `seconds -= 1` instead (if you want to count down).

Also, you may want to update your `updateTimer()` method like this:

```
  func updateTimer() {

      seconds -= 1

      if seconds == 0 {
        timer.invalidate()
        isTimerRunning = false
      }

      shortTimerLabel.text = String(describing: seconds)
  }
```

An other issue here is that you added your `runTimer()` and `updateTimer()` method to the wrong place. You should not add them **inside** your `viewDidLoad` method.

Your final code would look like this:

```
var seconds = 60
var timer = Timer()
var isTimerRunning = false

@IBAction func longpressed(_ gestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
  resetTimer()
}

@IBAction func tappedShortTimer(_ gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
  stopStartTimer()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // ...
}

func stopStartTimer() {

   if !isTimerRunning {

      timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

      isTimerRunning = true

   } else {

      timer.invalidate()

      isTimerRunning = false

   }
}

func updateTimer() {

   seconds -= 1

   if seconds == 0 {
      timer.invalidate()
      isTimerRunning = false
   }

   shortTimerLabel.text = String(describing: seconds)
}

func resetTimer() {

   if isTimerRunning {

      seconds = 60

      timer.invalidate()

      isTimerRunning = false

      stopStartTimer()
   }
}
```

Comment: @M4YDIE, If this answer helped you, please mark it as accepted so it can help others that are looking for the same answer. :) If you any other questions please feel free asking me!

Comment: Im still getting a similar error, "Argument of '#selector' refers to instance method 'updateTimer()' that is not exposed to Objective-C" I should have noted that im working in a "SecondViewController" if that makes any difference?

Comment: changing it to Selector(("updateTimer")) appears to fix the error but it crashes on button press

Comment: I see ! Yes it does make a difference indeed. This would work if the method and the timer are in the same controller. But if they aren't, they you would need to adjust the selector depending on your situation

Comment: Your selector is fine, #selector(updateTimer) is the proper way to write a selector in Swift 4. But the problem seems to be that your class doesn't inherit from NSObject so its public methods are not exposed to Objective-C automatically. You could fix the problem by adding the @objc attribute in front of your updateTimer() method, to indicate that you want this method to be exposed to Objective-C.

Comment: Ahh fantastic, they were in the same controller. Changing it to @objc func appears to get it working. Thanks so much for your assistance!

Answer (score 1):

- The selector should be given in the form `#selector(ViewController.updateTimer)`
- You shouldn't declare functions in the `viewDidLoad` but outside
- You only set the timer in the `longpressed` function
- For stoping it is `timer.invalidate()`

Comment: Since he is using @IBActions to set up his Gesture Recognizers (if everything is properly connected) it's completely fine not declaring #selector(ViewController.updateTimer) in the viewDidLoad.